# How to verify transformed text in a textbox with Selenium Java

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver

The web app I am trying to validate has a textbox that instantly transforms entered lower-case letters to capital letters:

```
<input id="myField" style="text-transform: uppercase; background-color:
rgb(255, 255, 255);" type="text" size="2" maxlength="2" value="">
```

I'd like to validate that when I enter "ab", "AB" is displayed in the textbox, but this code,

```
driver.findElement( By.id( "myField" ) ).getAttribute( "value" );
```

just returns the text exactly as entered (e.g., "ab"), and

```
driver.findElement( By.id( "myField" ) ).getText();
```

returns null.

Comment: you can also simply get the text and change it to uppercase to match your test criteria... also can you look into this https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/issues/3778 ...

Comment: Yes, I saw that issue; I'm having the exact opposite problem: I want to get back the text all capitalized, but can't (and from an input box, not just page text).

Answer (score 0):

try adding wait before fetching uppercase letters

```
String entered_text = "ab";
// WebDriver wait
wait.until(ExpectedConditions.textToBePresentInElement(driver.findElement(By.id("myField")), entered_text.toUpperCase()));
```